# Why is BSOD "KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED" happening (crash report: tcpip.sys, ntoskrnl.exe, netio.sys, ndu.sys) on Windows 8.1 Pro x64?

Tags: windows, bsod

everyone!
I need your help!

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro x64.
I reinstalled it, but the problem is remaining.

BSOD happens about 1-2 time in a day.
I noticed that if it happens, it frequently happens in few minutes after I start to download something using "uTorrent".

Motherboard: "Asus M4A78LT-M LE". My network driver: "Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)".
I tried to install an old version, but the problem did remain.

My UAC and Windows Defender are off. Firewall is on.

Here's a link to some info I extracted: 
http://www.beetxt.com/printable.php?view=ydP

(sorry it's in russian, cause I have russian Windows)

Here are the dump files (they are in .rar archive):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByigE0NW6WLIaUpKSkgtcnFqR1E/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Hardware problem; run memtest; also: wrong site.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe, memtest went well, no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it comes up again, it's probably L1C63x64.sys, not tcpip.sys. It's the driver of your qualcomm card, shows up in the stack of two of your minidumps just before tcpip.sys. Its timestamp is April 01 2013, while there is supposedly a newer one on your [motherboard's support site](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A78LTM_LE/HelpDesk_Download/), updated at 2013/09/30.
Another option is giving a shot to [an **un**official driver](https://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=48&system=8), as a last resort solution.

Answer (score -1):

Check Windows Event Log for events near the BSOD time.  You are having a problem with tcpip.sys driver.

Comment: I can find some errors there - warnings: 16393, 1014, 219. Error: 7030, 10010, 7009, 7031, 7000, 1001, 6008 and a lot of 36888. And only one critical error, that shows up in time just after the BSOD restart: 41.

Comment: Dimitry,  Looking at the dumps, everything points to a network adapter problem,  I would first make sure that your adapter is OS compatible and then, make sure that you have the latest drivers installed.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I just changed my "uTorrent" to another version and also I did take off all the TLS and SSL ticks off in Internet Explorer settings (it was suggested to do so with 36888 error that I saw in Windows journal multiple times before this BSOD) and for now the BSOD is not to happening again. Not since the last time two days ago, before I did these changes. And now it's not even happening when I'm forcing it by making a lot of downloads in "uTorrent". I start to think that this could've been the problem - the "uTorrent" or 36888. Anyways, for now it's fixed, hope it'll work.